# Leap Motion Controller - not connecting cpp, python (mac)

Tags: python, c++, leap-motion

I downloaded the SDK from https://developer.leapmotion.com/sdk-leap-motion-controller and tried running the code under samples. It works for java and javascript but doesn't work for cpp and python.

The controller is connected and working. And the service 'leapd' is running in the background.

Any idea what might be the cause?

I am on macOS (Big Sur 11.1)

EDIT:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── include
│   ├── Leap.h
│   └── LeapMath.h
├── lib
│   └── libLeap.dylib
├── main
└── main.cpp
```

```cpp
/******************************************************************************\
* Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Leap Motion, Inc. All rights reserved.               *
* Leap Motion proprietary and confidential. Not for distribution.              *
* Use subject to the terms of the Leap Motion SDK Agreement available at       *
* https://developer.leapmotion.com/sdk_agreement, or another agreement         *
* between Leap Motion and you, your company or other organization.             *
\******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Leap.h"

using namespace Leap;

class SampleListener : public Listener {
  public:
    virtual void onInit(const Controller&);
    virtual void onConnect(const Controller&);
    virtual void onDisconnect(const Controller&);
    virtual void onExit(const Controller&);
    virtual void onFrame(const Controller&);
    virtual void onFocusGained(const Controller&);
    virtual void onFocusLost(const Controller&);
    virtual void onDeviceChange(const Controller&);
    virtual void onServiceConnect(const Controller&);
    virtual void onServiceDisconnect(const Controller&);

  private:
};

const std::string fingerNames[] = {"Thumb", "Index", "Middle", "Ring", "Pinky"};
const std::string boneNames[] = {"Metacarpal", "Proximal", "Middle", "Distal"};
const std::string stateNames[] = {"STATE_INVALID", "STATE_START", "STATE_UPDATE", "STATE_END"};

void SampleListener::onInit(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Initialized" << std::endl;
}

void SampleListener::onConnect(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;
  controller.enableGesture(Gesture::TYPE_CIRCLE);
  controller.enableGesture(Gesture::TYPE_KEY_TAP);
  controller.enableGesture(Gesture::TYPE_SCREEN_TAP);
  controller.enableGesture(Gesture::TYPE_SWIPE);
}

void SampleListener::onDisconnect(const Controller& controller) {
  // Note: not dispatched when running in a debugger.
  std::cout << "Disconnected" << std::endl;
}

void SampleListener::onExit(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Exited" << std::endl;
}

void SampleListener::onFrame(const Controller& controller) {
  // Get the most recent frame and report some basic information
  const Frame frame = controller.frame();
  std::cout << "Frame id: " << frame.id()
            << ", timestamp: " << frame.timestamp()
            << ", hands: " << frame.hands().count()
            << ", extended fingers: " << frame.fingers().extended().count()
            << ", tools: " << frame.tools().count()
            << ", gestures: " << frame.gestures().count() << std::endl;

  HandList hands = frame.hands();
  for (HandList::const_iterator hl = hands.begin(); hl != hands.end(); ++hl) {
    // Get the first hand
    const Hand hand = *hl;
    std::string handType = hand.isLeft() ? "Left hand" : "Right hand";
    std::cout << std::string(2, ' ') << handType << ", id: " << hand.id()
              << ", palm position: " << hand.palmPosition() << std::endl;
    // Get the hand's normal vector and direction
    const Vector normal = hand.palmNormal();
    const Vector direction = hand.direction();

    // Calculate the hand's pitch, roll, and yaw angles
    std::cout << std::string(2, ' ') <<  "pitch: " << direction.pitch() * RAD_TO_DEG << " degrees, "
              << "roll: " << normal.roll() * RAD_TO_DEG << " degrees, "
              << "yaw: " << direction.yaw() * RAD_TO_DEG << " degrees" << std::endl;

    // Get the Arm bone
    Arm arm = hand.arm();
    std::cout << std::string(2, ' ') <<  "Arm direction: " << arm.direction()
              << " wrist position: " << arm.wristPosition()
              << " elbow position: " << arm.elbowPosition() << std::endl;

    // Get fingers
    const FingerList fingers = hand.fingers();
    for (FingerList::const_iterator fl = fingers.begin(); fl != fingers.end(); ++fl) {
      const Finger finger = *fl;
      std::cout << std::string(4, ' ') <<  fingerNames[finger.type()]
                << " finger, id: " << finger.id()
                << ", length: " << finger.length()
                << "mm, width: " << finger.width() << std::endl;

      // Get finger bones
      for (int b = 0; b < 4; ++b) {
        Bone::Type boneType = static_cast<Bone::Type>(b);
        Bone bone = finger.bone(boneType);
        std::cout << std::string(6, ' ') <<  boneNames[boneType]
                  << " bone, start: " << bone.prevJoint()
                  << ", end: " << bone.nextJoint()
                  << ", direction: " << bone.direction() << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }

  // Get tools
  const ToolList tools = frame.tools();
  for (ToolList::const_iterator tl = tools.begin(); tl != tools.end(); ++tl) {
    const Tool tool = *tl;
    std::cout << std::string(2, ' ') <<  "Tool, id: " << tool.id()
              << ", position: " << tool.tipPosition()
              << ", direction: " << tool.direction() << std::endl;
  }

  // Get gestures
  const GestureList gestures = frame.gestures();
  for (int g = 0; g < gestures.count(); ++g) {
    Gesture gesture = gestures[g];

    switch (gesture.type()) {
      case Gesture::TYPE_CIRCLE:
      {
        CircleGesture circle = gesture;
        std::string clockwiseness;

        if (circle.pointable().direction().angleTo(circle.normal()) <= PI/2) {
          clockwiseness = "clockwise";
        } else {
          clockwiseness = "counterclockwise";
        }

        // Calculate angle swept since last frame
        float sweptAngle = 0;
        if (circle.state() != Gesture::STATE_START) {
          CircleGesture previousUpdate = CircleGesture(controller.frame(1).gesture(circle.id()));
          sweptAngle = (circle.progress() - previousUpdate.progress()) * 2 * PI;
        }
        std::cout << std::string(2, ' ')
                  << "Circle id: " << gesture.id()
                  << ", state: " << stateNames[gesture.state()]
                  << ", progress: " << circle.progress()
                  << ", radius: " << circle.radius()
                  << ", angle " << sweptAngle * RAD_TO_DEG
                  <<  ", " << clockwiseness << std::endl;
        break;
      }
      case Gesture::TYPE_SWIPE:
      {
        SwipeGesture swipe = gesture;
        std::cout << std::string(2, ' ')
          << "Swipe id: " << gesture.id()
          << ", state: " << stateNames[gesture.state()]
          << ", direction: " << swipe.direction()
          << ", speed: " << swipe.speed() << std::endl;
        break;
      }
      case Gesture::TYPE_KEY_TAP:
      {
        KeyTapGesture tap = gesture;
        std::cout << std::string(2, ' ')
          << "Key Tap id: " << gesture.id()
          << ", state: " << stateNames[gesture.state()]
          << ", position: " << tap.position()
          << ", direction: " << tap.direction()<< std::endl;
        break;
      }
      case Gesture::TYPE_SCREEN_TAP:
      {
        ScreenTapGesture screentap = gesture;
        std::cout << std::string(2, ' ')
          << "Screen Tap id: " << gesture.id()
          << ", state: " << stateNames[gesture.state()]
          << ", position: " << screentap.position()
          << ", direction: " << screentap.direction()<< std::endl;
        break;
      }
      default:
        std::cout << std::string(2, ' ')  << "Unknown gesture type." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
  }

  if (!frame.hands().isEmpty() || !gestures.isEmpty()) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

}

void SampleListener::onFocusGained(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Focus Gained" << std::endl;
}

void SampleListener::onFocusLost(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Focus Lost" << std::endl;
}

void SampleListener::onDeviceChange(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Device Changed" << std::endl;
  const DeviceList devices = controller.devices();

  for (int i = 0; i < devices.count(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "id: " << devices[i].toString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  isStreaming: " << (devices[i].isStreaming() ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
  }
}

void SampleListener::onServiceConnect(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Service Connected" << std::endl;
}

void SampleListener::onServiceDisconnect(const Controller& controller) {
  std::cout << "Service Disconnected" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Create a sample listener and controller
  SampleListener listener;
  Controller controller;

  // Have the sample listener receive events from the controller
  controller.addListener(listener);

  if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "--bg") == 0)
    controller.setPolicy(Leap::Controller::POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);

  // Keep this process running until Enter is pressed
  std::cout << "Press Enter to quit..." << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();

  // Remove the sample listener when done
  controller.removeListener(listener);

  return 0;
}
```

```sh
LEAP_LIBRARY := ./lib/libLeap.dylib

main: main.cpp
    $(CXX) -Wall -g -I ./include main.cpp -o main $(LEAP_LIBRARY);
    install_name_tool -change @loader_path/libLeap.dylib ./lib/libLeap.dylib main

clean:
    rm -rf main main.dSYM
```

```
$ otool -L lib/libLeap.dylib
lib/libLeap.dylib:
    @loader_path/libLeap.dylib (compatibility version 0.7.0, current version 2.3.1)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1265.21.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 48.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, as I had this question for a long time (My leap motion also, had this problem a while ago, now it's a diff. one  though)  Will follow and monitor this closely;

Comment: Updated the post with more details